# How do I check if every consecutive list element is equal to or 1 more than the last?

Tags: python, list

> Input: a list a of real numbers, of length 0 or greater. 
> Output: the Boolean value `True` if for every `i` in the list `a`, `a[i] <= a[i+1]`, 
> otherwise `False`.

This is what I have so far but it doesn't work:

```
def consecutive_elements_equal_or_one_more(a):
    for i in range(a)
        for i+1 in range(a)
            if a[i] <= a[i+1]:
                return true
            else:
                return false
```

`[1, 2, 3]` should return true.
`[1, 2, 2]` should return true.
`[1, 3, 2]` should return false.

Comment: You do not need two for loops. `for i+1 in range(a)` does not make sense; you cannot assign a value to `i+1`, and you have no reason to: it's one higher than `i`.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! This is overall a pretty solid question: it's good that you've included sample output, and that you've shown your attempt! Good job. However, lines like: `for i in range(a) ` is missing the terminating `:`, your indentation is incorrect, and `for i+1 in range(a) ` does not make sense. I would recommend reviewing how `for` loops work in any form of Python tutorial.

Comment: You condition writes its own code: `all(a[i]<=a[i+1] for i in range(0,len(a)-1))`

Answer (score 1):

Solution without third party libraries:

```py
ls = [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [1, 2, 2],
    [1, 3, 2]
]

for l in ls:
    print(all(a - b <= 1 for a, b in zip(l, [l[0] - 1, *l])))
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on these conditions you need to check if the list is already sorted.

Simple solution:

```
def is_sorted(a):
    return a == sorted(a)
```

Faster, without sorting the list first:

```
def is_sorted(a):
    for i in range(len(a) - 1):
        if a[i] > a[i + 1]:
            return False
    return True
```

Comment: Worth noting that `sorted` is highly optimized for partially sorted lists, and will detect a fully sorted list in O(n) time without actually trying to do any "additional" sorting.

Comment: (Strictly speaking, that's probably an implementation detail of CPython, but the sorting algorithm used--TimSort--is also used in other languages, so I would be surprised if another Python implementation didn't use it as well.)

Comment: Yes, that's true, I am aware of TimSort :) Please note it will still have O(n log(n)) performance if the list has high entropy. Hence the complexity is O(n log(n)). BTW, I like the solution mentioned in the comment under the question that utilizes `all` instead of plain for like my second approach.

Answer (score 0):

Your question title and problem statement are inconsistent.

Checking for non decreasing order can be done with `all` and `zip`:

```
if all(a<=b for a,b in zip(a,a[1:])):
```

Checking for "one or more than the last":

```
if all(a+1<=b for a,b in zip(a,a[1:])):
```